# Passing columns to "with" in lapply

Tags: r, lapply, with-statement

How can I pass columns of a dataframe to the `with` function in an `lapply` call?

I have tried these and they do not work!

```
lapply(data[ , grepl( "Measured." , names( data ) ) ], with, (. <= 5 & . >= 1) | . == 4244)

lapply(data[ , grepl( "Measured." , names( data ) ) ], function(x) with((x <= 5 & x >= 1) | x == 4244))
```

I am trying to see if the values in `Measured.` columns are between `1` and `5` and furthermore `4244` is also accepted.

Sample dataset:

```
data <- structure(list(ID = 1:10, Date = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2015L, 
2018L, 2015L, 2015L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L), Gender = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    Measured.1 = c(1L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L), Measured.2 = c(9L, 
    2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 7L), Measured.3 = c(9L, 4L, 
    35L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), Measured.4 = c(12L, 8L, 
    50L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Text = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    Test = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Date", "Gender", "Measured.1", "Measured.2", "Measured.3", "Measured.4", 
"Text", "Test"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

And its output:

```
   ID Date Gender Measured.1 Measured.2 Measured.3 Measured.4 Text Test
1   1 2018      M          1          9          9         12    N    5
2   2 2018      M          7          2          4          8    N    5
3   3 2018      M          1          4         35         50    N    5
4   4 2015      M          6          5          3          7    N    5
5   5 2018      M          6          2          4          2    N    5
6   6 2015      M          2          3          2          6    Y    6
7   7 2015      F          5          6          2          2    Y    6
8   8 2014      F          4          3          1          2    Y    6
9   9 2014      F          2          7          3          1    N    6
10 10 2014      F          6          7          4          2    N    6
```

Comment: please provide code to make reproducible data

Comment: @griffinevo Done.

Comment: Also good to have an illustration of the intended output (modify the example data frame by hand to show what the working solution would produce) - it makes the aim much clearer

Comment: Are you looking for `which` instead of `with` ?

Comment: What should your function do? What value should be returned for one column of your data?

Comment: I am trying to see if the values in `Measured.` columns are between `1` and `5` and furthermore `4244` is also accepted.

Comment: so you want to know which rows of *data* have either: at least one entry of "4244" in the *measured* columns, or where all *measured* columns are >= 1 and <= 5?

Comment: `data[data[,1][data[,4] >= 1 & data[,4] <= 5 & data[,5] >= 1 & data[,5] <= 5 & data[,6] >= 1 & data[,6] <= 5 & data[,7] >= 1 & data[,7] <= 5 | data[,4] == 4244 | data[,5] == 4244 | data[,6] == 4244 | data[,7] == 4244],]`

Comment: @xeyetopewu Do you want `lapply(data[ , grepl( "Measured." , names( data ) ) ], function(x) ((x <= 5 & x >= 1) | x == 4244))` ? or the variant `mytest <- function(x) ((x <= 5 & x >= 1) | x == 4244); 
mytest(data[ , grepl( "Measured." , names( data ) ) ])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from base `R` you could use a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("Measured")), 
            any_vars((. >= 1 & . <= 5) | . == 4244))
```

This would look for records where at least *one* of the `Measured` columns have a value between 1 and 5 or 4244.
If you want to be restrictive and *all*  values need to be within this range, you could change it to:

```
data %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("Measured")), 
            all_vars((. >= 1 & . <= 5) | . == 4244))
```

---

The former produces

```
   ID Date Gender Measured.1 Measured.2 Measured.3 Measured.4 Text Test
1   1 2018      M          1          9          9         12    N    5
2   2 2018      M          7          2          4          8    N    5
3   3 2018      M          1          4         35         50    N    5
4   4 2015      M          6          5          3          7    N    5
5   5 2018      M          6          2          4          2    N    5
6   6 2015      M          2          3          2          6    Y    6
7   7 2015      F          5          6          2          2    Y    6
8   8 2014      F          4          3          1          2    Y    6
9   9 2014      F          2          7          3          1    N    6
10 10 2014      F          6          7          4          2    N    6
```

While the latter yields

```
  ID Date Gender Measured.1 Measured.2 Measured.3 Measured.4 Text Test
1  8 2014      F          4          3          1          2    Y    6
```

---

The same can be done in a much faster (but imo less readable) way with base `R`:
You could use a base `R` approach with masks and `apply`:

```
# set up the cols of interest
colmask <- grepl("^Measured", names(data))

# apply the function rowwise (=1)
rowmask <- apply(data[colmask], 1, function(col) {
  any(((col >= 1 & col <= 5) | col == 4244))
})
data[rowmask,]
```

Or

```
colmask <- grepl("^Measured", names(data))
rowmask <- apply(data[colmask], 1, function(col) {
  all(((col >= 1 & col <= 5) | col == 4244))
})
data[rowmask,]
```

Obviously this yields the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, you can extract the rows that match these criteria as:

```
data[data[,1][data[,4] >= 1 & data[,4] <= 5 & data[,5] >= 1 & data[,5] <= 5 & data[,6] >= 1 & data[,6] <= 5 & data[,7] >= 1 & data[,7] <= 5 | data[,4] == 4244 | data[,5] == 4244 | data[,6] == 4244 | data[,7] == 4244],]
```

I'm using the `&` to create additive criteria (you're looking for rows where measured.1, measured.2, measured.3 and measured.4 are all `>= 1` and `<= 5`) and `|` to create alternative criteria (any measured value is `4424`):

Giving:

```
  ID Date Gender Measured.1 Measured.2 Measured.3 Measured.4 Text Test
8  8 2014      F          4          3          1          2    Y    6
```

It's not the prettiest piece of code, but (according to microbenchmark) it is 43x faster to run than the dplyr approach from Jan.

Comment: +1 for taking the hard way but consider applying a mask (see the lower part of my answer), your code is not very readable and error-prone in a couple of weeks :)